# My bot works fine in the emulator,even with Microsoft app id and password but when I'm testing it online it fails

Tags: azure, botframework

My bot works fine in the emulator, even with Microsoft app id and password but when I'm testing it at https://dev.botframework.com I get a message

> couldn't send message retry

I get a

> 401 unauthorized

error when I'm trying to get a reply from the emulator with bot url https://botwebdeployment.azurewebsites.net/ (deployed in azure).

I have added my bot bot in Microsoft bot directory and have enabled Skype, but even on my machine I can send message on Skype app  to bot but I don't get any reply.

Comment: Try to interact with your bot using bot emulator. The communication url should be `https://botwebdeployment.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`. After that you can see the error messages.

Comment: Yes, I did that and I see a 401 unauthorized error

Comment: Check this article for error 401 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/08/01/bot-framework-405-method-not-allowed-401-unauthorized-and-500-internal-server-error-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify application settings - confirm you've updated the Microsoft App ID & Password then deploy to Azure again.
2. Verify HTTPS endpoint - In the dev portal (https://dev.botframework.com), settings page; make sure you used HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-visual-studio

Comment: Republished it  and now it works fine.I guess the issue was with Microsoft App ID and App Password.